# Is it better to escape characters like quotes on read from database or at write time?

Tags: json, database, escaping, substitution

I couldn't find a good answer on this topic yet it must be a common question. Many applications nowadays just pull data to and from a database and output either JSON or XML directly to an external client. So at what point in the process is it best to escape problem characters like `"` or `<`?

If you output the name Dwayne "The Rock" Johnson in JSON you will get:

```
{"name":"Dwayne "The Rock" Johnson"} //breaks
```

..which will break the JSON and your app will crash, so it needs to be output as:

```
{"name":"Dwayne \"The Rock\" Johnson"} //ok
```

using the backslash `\` to escape the quotes.
In Perl we can do a simple regex replace before outputting the data, something like:

```
$name =~ s/"/\\"/g; #replaces " with \"
```

My question is that although I'm sure it's bad practice to permanently alter your data to escape any problem characters, surely it is also bad practice to use so much server overhead making constant character substitutions on every read from database when it could have been only done once? How do you approach this issue?

Answer (score 2):

Escape the value when serializing, not when saving. You never know what formats you'll need to serialize to; different formats will have different escaping requirements.

---

Separately: Don't create JSON manually. Use a serializer (which will handle the quotes for you).

Comment: +1 The data should be persisted in its raw form. Do not pollute persisted data with rendering related info. Also, do not presuppose uses of the data. Keep it vanilla.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean that you store in the database the values of separate attributes of the object that need later be represented as JSON or XML? If yes, better is to store the original plain values and escape only when you are generating JSON or XML. Otherwise it will break or essentially complicate other operations like search and indexing. Furthermore, if you have later format that needs no escaping (like HTML) you would need to remove escaping.

Briefly: Store plain text. Escape special chars after reading, before creating JSON or XML.